# Как правильно сверстать блок с иконками?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Есть вот [такой блок](http://prntscr.com/n6yq7c)

[image: скриншот]

как видно заголовок и название идет четко друг под другом. Я пытаюсь сверстать его вот так

```css
.advantages{
 float:left;
 width:570px;
}

.advantages_icon-eye{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width:31px;
 height:20px;
 background-color:red;
}

.advantages_icon-brush{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width:31px;
 height:31px;
 background-color:green;
}

.advantages_icon-heart{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 width:31px;
 height:27px;
 background-color:blue;
}

.advantages_name{
 text-transform: uppercase;;
 color:#000;
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
   <div class="advantages">
    <div class="advantages__item">
     <span class="advantages_icon-eye"></span>
     <div class="advantages_name clearfix">
      1. Lorem ipsum
     </div>
     <div class="advantages_description">Ut porttitor quam nec risus ultricies efficitur. Pellentesque sagittis sed magna scelerisque consectetur.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="advantages__item">
     <span class="advantages_icon-brush"></span>
     <div class="advantages_name clearfix">
      2. Lorem ipsum
     </div>
     <div class="advantages_description">Ut porttitor quam nec risus ultricies efficitur. Pellentesque sagittis sed magna scelerisque consectetur.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="advantages__item">
     <span class="advantages_icon-heart"></span>
     <div class="advantages_name clearfix">
      3. Lorem ipsum
     </div>
     <div class="advantages_description">Ut porttitor quam nec risus ultricies efficitur. Pellentesque sagittis sed magna scelerisque consectetur.</div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Но в моем варианте мне нужно увеличивать высоту каждой иконки чтобы сдвинуть текст, чтобы он встал нормально. Подскажите правильно ли это и если нет, то как сделать иначе?

P.S. flex не предлагать))) я пока что хочу float постигнуть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В вашем случае постижение float ведет к мракобесию и скверному результату. То, что вы делаете, неправильно с точки зрения подхода.
2. Постичь flex будет проще, понимание происходящего - полнее, а результат - лучше.
3. В вашем случае flex тоже не нужен. Я бы сделал `padding-left` у блоков `.advantages__item`, а иконки расположил в виде фоновых изображений либо с абсолютным позиционированием. А можно вообще таблицей сверстать, если так уж хочется освоить антикварные технологии.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul, li, h2, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  width: 570px;
  margin: auto;
  list-style: none;
}

i {
  float: left;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

h2, p {
  margin-left: 2.5rem;
}

li:hover {
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <i></i>
    <h2>1. Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>Ut porttitor quam nec risus ultricies efficitur. Pellentesque sagittis sed magna scelerisque consectetur.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i></i>
    <h2>1. Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>Ut porttitor quam nec risus ultricies efficitur. Pellentesque sagittis sed magna scelerisque consectetur.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i></i>
    <h2>1. Lorem ipsum</h2>
    <p>Ut porttitor quam nec risus ultricies efficitur. Pellentesque sagittis sed magna scelerisque consectetur.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Недавно отвечал на [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/965454/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-css-html/965475#965475), вот прям один в один.

Решение на `float`

```css
.ul-li > .li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 7%;
}

.ul-li > .li::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.ul-li > .li img, .ul-li > .li .text {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.ul-li > .li img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.ul-li > .li .text {
  width: calc(92% - 40px);
  margin-left: 8%;
}

.ul-li > .li .text h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ul-li">
  <div class="li">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhysK.png" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      <h4>Title</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="li">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhysK.png" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      <h4>Title</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```