# Как правильно позиционировать элементы в блоке? CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Есть картинка и с права от неё заголовок и параграф. Верстаю с помощью flexbox css. Подскажите как правильно их соединить чтобы они выглядели как на фото.
В моем варианте не будет видно картинки, так как они не с инета взяты. Ниже приложу фото картинки
Мой вариант (все держится на соплях):

```css
.block-3 .text .ul-li .text {
    margin-left: 8%;
    margin-top: -7%; 
}
.block-3 .text .ul-li img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ul-li">
                    <img src="img/block-3_for_ul.png" alt="">
                    <div class="text">
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/block-3_for_ul.png" alt="">
                    <div class="text">
                        <h4>Title</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Как должно выглядить
[image: Как должно быть]

А вот и картинка
[image: Картинка]

Comment: Ну во-первых объедени в блок текст и картинку. А затем задай display: flex; flex-direction: row; Ты написал что верстаешь с помощью флекс разметки, а где она в коде? Просто какой-то кусок кода в котором ну вообще нет этого тега.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы использовал такую конструкцию

```css
.ul-li > .li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 7%;
}

.ul-li > .li::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.ul-li > .li img, .ul-li > .li .text {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.ul-li > .li img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.ul-li > .li .text {
  width: calc(92% - 40px);
  margin-left: 8%;
}

.ul-li > .li .text h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ul-li">
  <div class="li">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhysK.png" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      <h4>Title</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="li">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhysK.png" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      <h4>Title</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно обвернуть те блоки в один элемент (в нашем случаи это div с классом some, а это классу можно дать 
и уже отталкиваясь от задачи позиционировать свою картинку

```css
.ul-li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.some {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="ul-li">
  <div class='some'>
    <img src="img/block-3_for_ul.png" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      <h4>Title</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing введите сюда кодelit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='some'>
    <img src="img/block-3_for_ul.png" alt="">
    <div class="text">
      <h4>Title</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```